ant build fails with eclipse but succeeds directly
I am facing below issue while trying build using ANT in eclispse
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.15 compiled on August 25 2024
Setting ro project property: ant.file -> C:\Install\eclipse-workspace\pf-sdk\build.xml
Buildfile: C:\Install\eclipse-workspace\pf-sdk\build.xml
Adding reference: ant.projectHelper
Adding reference: ant.parsing.context
Adding reference: ant.targets
parsing buildfile C:\Install\eclipse-workspace\pf-sdk\build.xml with URI = file:/C:/Install/eclipse-workspace/pf-sdk/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.project.default-target -> help
Setting ro project property: ant.project.name -> pf-sdk
Adding reference: pf-sdk
Setting ro project property: ant.file.pf-sdk -> C:\Install\eclipse-workspace\pf-sdk\build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type.pf-sdk -> file
Project base dir set to: C:\Install\PingFederate\pingfederate-12.1.4\pingfederate\sdk
+Target:
+Target: -plugin-init
+Target: compile-plugin
+Target: jar-plugin
+Target: deploy-plugin
+Target: clean-plugin
+Target: compile-services
+Target: jar-services
+Target: clean-services 
+Target: deploy-services
+Target: help
Adding reference: ant.LocalProperties
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Install/apache-ant-1.10.15/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Install/apache-ant-1.10.15/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
[property] Loading C:\Install\PingFederate\pingfederate-12.1.4\pingfederate\sdk\build.local.properties
Setting project property: target-plugin.name -> template-render-adapter-example
Setting project property: pingfederate.home -> ../
[property] Loading C:\Install\PingFederate\pingfederate-12.1.4\pingfederate\sdk\build.properties
Setting project property: pingfederate.sdk.lib.dir -> ..//sdk/lib
Setting project property: target-plugin.build.jar.dir -> plugin-src/template-render-adapter-example/build/jar
Setting project property: target-plugin.build.jar.prefix -> pf.plugins.
Setting project property: svcs-src.dir -> services-src
Setting project property: pingfederate.deploy.dir -> ..//server/default/deploy
Setting project property: svcs.build.dir -> services-src/build
Setting project property: target-plugin.build.dir -> plugin-src/template-render-adapter-example/build
Setting project property: pingfederate.servlet.jar.name -> servlet-api.jar
Setting project property: pingfederate.server.lib.dir -> ..//server/default/lib
Setting project property: pingfederate.lib.dir -> ..//lib
Setting project property: svcs.build.jar.dir -> services-src/build/jar
Setting project property: lib.dir -> lib
Setting project property: pingfederate.servlet.engine.dir -> ..//server/default/deploy/jetty.sar
Setting project property: target-plugin.build.classes.dir -> plugin-src/template-render-adapter-example/build/classes
Setting project property: svcs.jar.name -> pf-services-extensions.jar
Setting project property: javac.deprecation -> true
Setting project property: svcs.build.classes.dir -> services-src/build/classes
Setting project property: plugin-src.dir -> plugin-src
Setting project property: target-plugin.conf.dir -> plugin-src/template-render-adapter-example/conf
Setting project property: pingfederate.conf.dir -> ..//server/default/conf
Setting project property: target-plugin.build.jar.name -> pf.plugins.template-render-adapter-example.jar
Setting project property: javac.debug -> true
Setting project property: target-plugin.dir -> plugin-src/template-render-adapter-example
Adding reference: jars.patternset
Adding reference: pf.classpath
Adding reference: tasks.classpath
Adding reference: plugin.compile.classpath
Adding reference: services.compile.classpath
Setting ro project property: ant.project.invoked-targets -> deploy-plugin
Adding reference: eclipse.ant.targetVector
Build sequence for target(s) `deploy-plugin' is [-plugin-init, compile-plugin, jar-plugin, deploy-plugin]
Complete build sequence is [-plugin-init, compile-plugin, jar-plugin, deploy-plugin, clean-plugin, help, compile-services, jar-services, deploy-services, clean-services, ]
-plugin-init:
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\Install\PingFederate\pingfederate-12.1.4\pingfederate\server\default\lib with patternSet{ includes: [*.jar] excludes: [] }
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\Install\PingFederate\pingfederate-12.1.4\pingfederate\lib with patternSet{ includes: [*.jar] excludes: [] }
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\Install\PingFederate\pingfederate-12.1.4\pingfederate\sdk\lib with patternSet{ includes: [] excludes: [] }
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\Install\PingFederate\pingfederate-12.1.4\pingfederate\sdk\lib with patternSet{ includes: [*.jar] excludes: [] }
Finding class com.pingidentity.anttask.CheckTargetAdapterName
Loaded from C:\Install\PingFederate\pingfederate-12.1.4\pingfederate\sdk\lib\tasks.jar com/pingidentity/anttask/CheckTargetAdapterName.class
Class org.apache.tools.ant.Task loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class com.pingidentity.anttask.CheckTargetAdapterName loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.Map loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Throwable loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.List loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
+Datatype check-setup com.pingidentity.anttask.CheckTargetAdapterName
Class java.lang.String loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.Project loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.File loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
Loaded from C:\Install\PingFederate\pingfederate-12.1.4\pingfederate\server\default\lib\commons-lang.jar org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.class
Class java.lang.Object loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.IllegalStateException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Character loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.ArrayList loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)

BUILD FAILED
C:\Install\eclipse-workspace\pf-sdk\build.xml:49:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null 
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350) 
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449) 
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470) 
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1374) 
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:34)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264) 
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:143)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null 
    at com.pingidentity.anttask.CheckTargetAdapterName.getMsg(CheckTargetAdapterName.java:90)
    at com.pingidentity.anttask.CheckTargetAdapterName.execute(CheckTargetAdapterName.java:83)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) 
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    ... 10 more

Total time: 521 milliseconds

I am successfully able to build it directly using CMD with ant deploy-plugin command, however, when I do the same using eclipse, it gives above error.
I have configured eclipse to use the same ANT but still facing this issue.
build.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="C:\Install\PingFederate\pingfederate-12.1.4\pingfederate\sdk" default="help" name="pf-sdk">

<property file="build.local.properties"/>
<property file="build.properties"/>

<patternset id="jars.patternset">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
</patternset>

<path id="pf.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${pingfederate.server.lib.dir}">
      <patternset refid="jars.patternset"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${pingfederate.lib.dir}">
      <patternset refid="jars.patternset"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${pingfederate.sdk.lib.dir}">
      <filename name="${pingfederate.servlet.jar.name}"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="tasks.classpath">
    <path refid="pf.classpath"/>
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <patternset refid="jars.patternset"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="plugin.compile.classpath">
    <path refid="pf.classpath"/>
    <fileset dir="${target-plugin.dir}" defaultexcludes="true">
        <patternset includes="lib/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="services.compile.classpath">
    <path refid="pf.classpath"/>
    <fileset dir="${svcs-src.dir}" defaultexcludes="true">
        <patternset includes="lib/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="-plugin-init">
    <taskdef classname="com.pingidentity.anttask.CheckTargetAdapterName" name="check-setup">
        <classpath refid="tasks.classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <check-setup targetPropName="target-plugin.name" rootSrc="${plugin-src.dir}" classpathref="plugin.compile.classpath"/>
</target>

<target name="compile-plugin" depends="-plugin-init" >
       <mkdir dir="${target-plugin.build.classes.dir}" />
       <javac classpathref="plugin.compile.classpath"
              destdir="${target-plugin.build.classes.dir}"
              srcdir="${target-plugin.dir}/java"
              debug="${javac.debug}"
              deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
              includeAntRuntime="false"
              fork="true" />
</target>

<target name="jar-plugin" depends="compile-plugin" description="Package the plugin jar" >
    <taskdef classname="com.pingidentity.anttask.BuildSdkDeploymentDesc" name="build-pf-desc">
        <classpath refid="tasks.classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <build-pf-desc classesDir="${target-plugin.build.classes.dir}" classpathRef="plugin.compile.classpath"/>
    <mkdir dir="${target-plugin.build.jar.dir}" />
    <jar destfile="${target-plugin.build.jar.dir}/${target-plugin.build.jar.name}">
        <fileset dir="${target-plugin.build.classes.dir}"/>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="deploy-plugin" depends="jar-plugin" description="Deploy the plugin jar and libs to PingFederate">
    <copy todir="${pingfederate.deploy.dir}" flatten="true" >
        <fileset dir="${target-plugin.build.jar.dir}"/>
        <fileset dir="${target-plugin.dir}" defaultexcludes="true">
            <patternset includes="lib/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${pingfederate.conf.dir}" failonerror="false" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="${target-plugin.conf.dir}"/>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="clean-plugin" description="Clean the plugin build directory">
    <delete dir="${target-plugin.build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile-services">
    <mkdir dir="${svcs.build.classes.dir}"/>
    <javac classpathref="services.compile.classpath"
              destdir="${svcs.build.classes.dir}"
              srcdir="${svcs-src.dir}/java"
              debug="${javac.debug}"
              deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
              includeAntRuntime="false"
              fork="true"/>
</target>

<target name="jar-services" depends="compile-services">
    <mkdir dir="${svcs.build.jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${svcs.build.jar.dir}/${svcs.jar.name}">
        <fileset dir="${svcs.build.classes.dir}"/>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="clean-services">
    <delete dir="${svcs.build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="deploy-services" depends="jar-services">
    <copy todir="${pingfederate.server.lib.dir}" flatten="true">
        <fileset dir="${svcs.build.jar.dir}"/>
        <fileset dir="${svcs-src.dir}" defaultexcludes="true">
            <patternset includes="lib/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="help">
  <java classname="org.apache.tools.ant.Main">
    <arg value="-projecthelp"/>
    <classpath>
      <fileset dir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
    </classpath>
   </java> 
</target>
    

Any pointers would be helpful

If you post full error text and your build script, then not only telepathy enhanced humans could try to answer your question.

Updated the console output having error, also added build.xml

Add -debug parameter. It will print more details about error.

@talex Done and updated the question kindly check

Please show the output of both with the -debug parameter and add them into your question formatted as Sample Code to preserver line breaks and things like <local3>, not as quote (see e.g. Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null is shown as Cannot read the array length because "" is null).

It’s good that you included the Ant output, but we need you to paste it with all of the line breaks intact.  As a single massive run-on line, it is mostly unreadable.

The ultimate cause of the exception is Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null at com.pingidentity.anttask.CheckTargetAdapterName.getMsg(CheckTargetAdapterName.java:90).  The problem is in that custom Ant task.  If you wrote that task, show us the code of the getMsg method of the CheckTargetAdapterName class.

Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null at com.pingidentity.anttask.CheckTargetAdapterName.getMsg(CheckTargetAdapterName.java:90) seems the root cause. Do you know what the target adapter is referring to in this context? Does the output/log before the error differ from the output/log from running on the command line?
